# How can I find n smallest numbers without changing the order of the first list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I intend to get the `n` smallest numbers in a list but keep the numbers in the same order they appear in the list. For example:

This is my list:

```
A = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0]
```

I like to get the first three lowest numbers as it has been ordered in the first list:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```

I do not want to sort the result as:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

I have tried:

```
heapq.nsmallest(3,A)
```

but i wonder if it is possible to retain this list as:[1, 2, 0]

By the way, I'm not a Python coder so thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a homework completion website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) to get the `n` smallest elements from the list. Then use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a *multiset* from that list which you can use to check which elements from the original list to include in the result, e.g.

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0]
>>> n = 3    
>>> c = Counter(nsmallest(n, A))
>>> result = []
>>> for elem in A:
...     if c.get(elem, 0):
...         result.append(elem)
...         c[elem] -= 1
... 
>>> result
[1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
new_a = []
A=[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0]
for a in A:
   if a not in new_a:
      new_a.append(a)
new_a = [i for i in new_a if i in sorted(new_a)[:3]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: This is very inefficient as 1) `sorted()` is called for each item in `A` 2) The `i in sorted()` check becomes slow as `n` grows.

Comment: ...and in fact incorrect: consider the case when  `A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], n = 5`

Comment: If you exchange the last element,I mean 0, with 2 it would return:    [1, 3, 2]
which is unlike the answer:    [1, 2, 2]